# How to initialize a Vector instance by calling a method, defined in the same class-Vector?

Tags: python

So I want to initialize an instance ov a Vector class, with a tuple return by a method defined in that class.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def subtract(self, a, b):
        x = a.x - b.x
        y = a.y - b.y
        return x, y # <-- This tuple


p = Point(0, -1)
i = Point(1, 1)
# Here I want to call Vector.subtract(p, i) and assign this tuple to a Vector instance
```

I following vector tutorial's, but they are in C++ and the syntax there is so different from Python that I have no idea how I can do this.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you rewrite your method

```
def subtract(self, a, b):
    x = a.x - b.x
    y = a.y - b.y
    return x, y # <-- This tuple
```

to

```
def subtract(self, a, b):
    x = a.x - b.x
    y = a.y - b.y
    return Vector(x, y) # <-- This tuple
```

It is also weird that you declare the instance method `substract`, it is more reasonable to make it like this:

```
def subtract(self, b):
    x = self.x - b.x
    y = self.y - b.y
    return Vector(x, y) # <-- This tuple
```

So you can call

```
a = Vector(1,2)
b = Vector(4,1)
c = a.substract(b)
```

or at least make it a static method by removing the `self` reference

```
@staticmethod
def subtract(a, b):
    x = a.x - b.x
    y = a.y - b.y
    return Vector(x, y)  # <-- result as new Vector
```

and then use it like this

```
c = Vector.subtract(a, b)
```